# riak.conf changes needed for riak-cs to work

Tags: configuration, erlang, riak, riak-cs

I am trying to install riak-cs 1.5.3 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

It requires to setup riak first. I installed riak 2.0.0 and it starts gracefully with default settings. However for riak-cs to work, there are some settings that need to be changed on riak.

Refer this link http://docs.basho.com/riakcs/latest/cookbooks/configuration/Configuring-Riak/

This document seems to be old and revolves around app.config. However riak 2.0.0 don't have any app.config. Instead there's riak.conf. I am not sure which properties I should change in riak.conf, in order to make riak-cs work.

I changed storage_backend from bitcask to multi. But after making the change riak is not starting.

Any document that can point out changes needed to riak.conf for riak-cs to work would be helpful.

Comment: For riak-cs 2.0.1 and riak 2.1.1 I added a new adanced.config file that wasn't there, so maybe for your version although app.config is not there, if you create it, it will be picked up. For my version I followed this instructions to get multi backend working:
http://docs.basho.com/riakcs/latest/cookbooks/configuration/Configuring-Riak/#Setting-up-the-Proper-Riak-Backend

Answer (score 2):

Finally, figured out where the problem was. riak-cs doesn't work with riak version 2.0.0.

It requires older riak version 1.4.10. See this link for compatible version list http://docs.basho.com/riakcs/latest/cookbooks/installing/Installing-Riak-CS/

I downgraded riak to 1.4.10 version and voila, it worked !!

Answer (score 0):

At Riak CS 2.0.0 and after, one can use it with Riak 2.x.